# The definition and meaning of the Instantaneous rate of change

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Im a math major and I recently had to explain what the derivative is to someone I know. They later used the term "instantaneous rate of change" in school and I asked myself why that term is even being used and defined the way it is: as the derivative of a given function at a point x0. The way we viewed it in University has been the following: if the sequence of secants through points (x,f(x)) converges, then the limit of that sequence is defined as the tangent in x0 and it follows that its slope is the same as the derivative. And im totally fine with viewing it that way, since it's rigoros. As far as i know (correct me if I'm wrong) the "instantaneous rate of change", however, gives the change in f when the change of x is infinitely small. So consider an infinitely small change of x, then the gap between the difference quotient and the derivative in the point x0 should be infinitely small as well. In conclusion the "instantaneous rate of change" shouldn't exactly be the derivative, but rather approximately the derivative, shouldn't it? Im not a native english speaker, so I'm sorry for any language mistakes as well as mistakes in the things I said regarding the mathematical content. Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: What, precisely, is an “infinitely small change in $x$?”

Comment: The average rate of change of $f$ during a short time interval $[t, t + \Delta t]$ is $\frac{f(t + \Delta t) - f(t)}{\Delta t}$. The instantaneous rate of change of $f$ at time $t$ is $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{f(t + \Delta t) - f(t)}{\Delta t}$. The average rate of change approaches the instantaneous rate of change as $\Delta t$ approaches $0$. The main point of differential calculus is that it allows us to define and reason about instantaneous rates of change.

Comment: I asked myself about what an infinitely small change of something should be as well and the way i thought about it was the following (note: I might be wrong, It's just what came to my mind): the limit as x approaches x0 means, that x gets arbitrary close to x0, but never quite reaches x0, which means the gap between x and x0 becomes infinitely small. So if one defines the instantaneous rate of change as the rate of change in one point x0 instead of the one above, it would probably be the optimal thing to define it as f'(x0), since that is what it would be, if a change in a single point existed